# grails plugin dynamic bean creation

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I am trying to register a bean in my plugin, but the class(implementation) of that bean is configurable.

in my TestGrailsPlugin.groovy file:

```
def doWithSpring = {
    userListener("${ConfigurationHolder.config.userListenerClass}")
}
```

but this is not working! what should I do, I guess should be really easy task. but didnt find anywhere!

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the class dynamically with the `GrailsApplication`'s classloader:

```
def doWithSpring = {
   def clazz = application.classLoader.loadClass(application.config.userListenerClass)
   userListener(clazz)
}
```

Also note that I'm using `application.config` instead of using the holder class - the holders are deprecated in 2.0 and will be removed in a future release.